# How to generate centralized logs for spring boot microservices?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Suppose I have a micro service 1 running in server A and and service 2 is running in server B. The UI/client code is deployed in server 3. I would like to generate the logs for both the micro services in my UI server. However individual logs are generated for microservices in their own servers as mentioned in applications.properties , logging.path.

Question is how can we generate all logs in one place, say in UI /client server.Can it be be achieved in spring cloud config? or if not , can you help me mentioning some steps.?

Comment: go with spring boot admin it is best solution for your question

Comment: @kumar, I thing you can elaborate a little bit more on your comment, as you are saying it is the best solution, but why? why are the other options not so good?

Answer (score 4):

the easiest way to go is by using spring boot admin, your logs will be exposed via an Actuator endpoint so that you see all your logs from admin console.

[spring boot admin](https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/)

Answer (score 2):

You would deploy a central logging server (e.g. Graylog https://www.graylog.org/).
Then add a logging appender to every microservice, that will report to the logging server.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many options available in market ..

if you are looking for logging with analytics , log monitoring and alerts - then you can use centralized system for logs.

Centralized system such as **Splunk** or **Stackify** - are very good at logging and effective handling.

There is one more platform called - **Loggly** , it is kind of Laas - logging as a service

For ex to start with you can check out the implementation for splunk -

Overview

```
http://dev.splunk.com/view/splunk-logging-java/SP-CAAAE2K
```

implementation

```
http://dev.splunk.com/view/splunk-logging-java/SP-CAAAE3R
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite popular solution is ELK stack.